# C code not doing what it's supposed to

Tags: c

Beginner here.So I'm writing a code to prompt a user for two different numbers. The if statements says that if the number is <=0, it should prompt the user for a different number that satisfies it. However, every time I enter a positive number, this incorrect prompt still comes up. Kinda annoying. Can anyone set me on the right path here?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int finalPopulation(int size, int num_days) {
    if (num_days <= 1) {
        return size;
    } else {
        return finalPopulation(size, num_days - 1) + finalPopulation(size, num_days - 2);
    }
}

int main() {
    int size, num_days;
    char str[100];
    while (1) {
        printf("Please enter the initial size of the green curd: ");
        scanf("%s", &str);
        size = (char) str;
        if (size <= 0) {
            printf("I'm sorry that value is unrecognized or is negative.\nPlease enter the initial size of the green curd: ");
            scanf("%s", &str);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("Please enter the number of days: ");
    scanf("%d", &num_days);
    printf("With an initial population of %d pounds of crud growing for %d days.\nthefinal population would be %d pounds.\n", size, num_days, finalPopulation(size, num_days / 5));
    while (1) {
        printf("Would you like to continue?(y/n)");
        scanf("%s", &str);
        if (str[0] == 'n') {
            return 0;
        } else if (str[0] == 'y') {
            break;
        } else {
            printf("I am sorry that answer is not recognized.\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How did you decide that you need the statement `size = (char)str;`?

Comment: You're casting a pointer (4+ bytes) to a character (1 byte), probably you are reading zero, or signed negative, there

Comment: Why not just use an `int` like you do for `num_days`?

Comment: @Kerrek  size = atoi(str); kept coming up as an error, so i decided to try something different.

Comment: **never ever** use `scanf("%s", )`, not even as a beginner. Read about `gets()` which has the equivalent problem -> **buffer overflow**. For reading just a string, there are better functions (->`fgets()`). For `%s` in `scanf`, **always** use a field width.

Comment: @jonagon: Do not assume a specific (or minimum) size for a pointer (it is not necessary here anyway). The standard does not specify a minimum size for a pointer.

Comment: @Olaf I'm old enough to remember 8 bit computing! On probability a beginner will be using Wintel IDE

Comment: @Olaf I think they were just guessing a common implementation that uses 32-bit or 64-bit pointers (excluding embedded systems). I think it's pretty safe to say the pointer is either 4 or 8 bytes in this case.

Comment: @PCLuddite: Casting a pointer to an `int` and reading the result is undefined by the standard anyway. It's not a matter of the the sizes. So why introduce them anyway?

Comment: @Olaf Fair enough. The behavior might be undefined, but it's pretty predictable. But yeah, there's never a good reason to do this kind of conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You made some errors. You took the size as a string ,the size should be taken as an int since it's a number.Strings are basically an array of characters.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int finalPopulation(int size, int num_days) {
    if (num_days <= 1) {
        return size;
    } else {
        return finalPopulation(size, num_days - 1) + finalPopulation(size, num_days - 2);
    }
}

int main() {
    int size, num_days;
    char str[100];
    while (1) {
        printf("Please enter the initial size of the green curd: ");
        scanf("%d", &size);

        if (size <= 0) {
            printf("I'm sorry that value is unrecognized or is negative.\nPlease enter the initial size of the green curd: ");
            scanf("%d", &size);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("Please enter the number of days: ");
    scanf("%d", &num_days);
    printf("With an initial population of %d pounds of crud growing for %d days.\nthefinal population would be %d pounds.\n", size, num_days, finalPopulation(size, num_days / 5));
    while (1) {
        printf("Would you like to continue?(y/n)");
        scanf("%s", &str);
        if (str[0] == 'n') {
            return 0;
        } else if (str[0] == 'y') {
            break;
        } else {
            printf("I am sorry that answer is not recognized.\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the event of invalid `size` input, you are still issuing a double request to enter green curd, and executing `scanf("%d", &size);` twice.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
size = (char) str;
```

is **not** how to convert a string to an integer. I'm not entirely sure why you thought it would.

This is the most common way to convert a string to an integer:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
size = atoi(str);
```

You mentioned in the comments that it didn't work though. My guess is that it's because you used the function without a prototype (i.e., you failed to include `stdlib.h`), but there are a number of reasons why the function would fail.

**However**, as you already know (because you used it later on), `scanf` can receive an integer value directly. You don't actually have to make any conversion.

```
scanf("%d", &size);
```